# create array of values if certain field is duplicate in array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like following:

```js
[
  [{
    "field": "gender_code",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "value": "Male"
  }, {
    "field": "gender_code",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "value": "Female"
  }],
  [{
    "field": "encounter_facility",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "value": "BS&W Facility 126"
  }, {
    "field": "encounter_facility",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "value": "BS&W Facility 608"
  }]
]
```

I want the objects with same field value to form array of values like following:

```
  [
    [{
      "field": "gender_code",
      "operator": "EQUALS",
      "value": ["Male", "Female"]
    }],
    [{
      "field": "encounter_facility",
      "operator": "EQUALS",
      "value": ["BS&W Facility 126", "BS&W Facility 608"]
    }]
  ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `reduce` to achieve it.

```js
let objects = [
  [{
    "field": "gender_code",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "value": "Male"
  }, {
    "field": "gender_code",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "value": "Female"
  }],
  [{
    "field": "encounter_facility",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "value": "BS&W Facility 126"
  }, {
    "field": "encounter_facility",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "value": "BS&W Facility 608"
  }]
];

objects = objects.map((items) => [
  items.reduce((carry, item) => {
    carry.value.push(item.value);
    return carry;
  }, {
    field: items[0].field,
    operator: items[0].operator,
    value: []
  })
]);

console.log(objects);
```